# Audio Not Playing on Imported Video Files

Tags: audio, after-effects

I a currently editing a video and imported a .avi movie into my After Effects project. I went to check the RAM preview, but there was no sound. I checked the audio preview and there still was no audio. I checked the waveform and it showed a straight lines, showing that there was no audio being produced from the video.

I checked the video to see if there was sound playing and I determined there was. I also have another .avi file in the project and it plays audio with no problem.

Please help! Thanks in advance!

**Update:** It works for some reason now... but now my characters are talking really fast and the video is going too fast! Help!!!

Fixed it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for a couple things, as there's more than one thing to cause this. First, make sure sure in your preview preferences that audio is enabled. Also, check that the duration isn't set to zero (default should be 30s, set it appropriately). Then RAM Preview with <kbd>0</kbd> on the number pad. You can scrub through audio only in the timeline by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+dragging (Windows) or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+dragging (Mac) to double-check existence of audio. You can also preview audio only by choosing Composition > Preview > Audio Preview.

More detail can be found at these two links:

[Adobe help document on previewing audio and video](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7ec9a.html#WSBFF42075-A759-4fd1-BAAE-5BA313E0923Ca).

[Adobe forum post about this issue](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/847056).

Comment: Well not it works, but the audio is sped up to 2x the speed and my characters sound like chipmunks. Could you help?

Comment: Never mind! The frame rate was at 29.97, causing my friend to talk like Alvin. xD Thanks!